# Finding method call in expression tree / iterating expression tree

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

I need to find all calls to particular method in expression tree which can be very complex. Currently I have simple recursive code which checks for BinaryExpression, ConditionalExpression etc and of course for MethodCallExpression. It works but I wonder if there is simpler way?

What I need is an iterator for all MethodCallExpression in complex expression so I can just check MethodCallExpression and don't care about other types of expression in my tree. Is something like this builtin for example somewhere in System.Linq.Expressions?

Comment: Show us the example you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As svick correctly points out: use the ExpressionVisitor base class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx

If you want to roll your own or see how ExpressionVisitor works, in this article Matt Warren shows you how to *rebuild* an expression tree by visiting every node.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx

You don't need to *rebuild* it, you just need to *search* it. You can modify Matt's code so that it does not return a new rebuilt expression, it just recursively searches each child node.

Comment: Or just use the base class that's already included in the Framework: [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx).

Comment: @svick: Good point, I had forgotten that we started including that.